# Setting shell for SSH directory users on a per-group basis in SSSD

Tags: active-directory, ssh, ldap, sssd

I have a network of Centos 7 machines hosting `sshd`, each of which is configured to lookup a user's public keys in an LDAP directory for ssh authentication.

Furthermore, all ssh users that have access to these Centos boxes are divided into one of two groups in the directory: users or admins.

I would like to make sure all users in the `users` group have their shell set to `/bin/false` and all users in the `admins` group have their shell set to `/bin/bash`.

In SSSD, the following successfully sets the shell for all users to `/bin/false`:

```
[domain/mydomain.com]
override_shell = /bin/false
```

Is there a way to set the shell for each AD group separately? Something like the following?

```
[domain/users@mydomain.com]
override_shell = /bin/false

[domain/admins@mydomain.com]
override_shell = /bin/bash
```

If so, how?

Comment: Are you trying to manage access to your machines (say for ssh logins)?

Comment: There must be a better way to do this, like for instance setting the shell in AD...

Comment: @Andy - I'm trying to make it so that only network admins can start a shell session in the SSH bastion server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Setting shell per user in AD would definitely be a maintenance nightmare--and not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to set the shell for users in particular groups on particular machines. Say user Joe is in the just-some-guy group. I want him to have /bin/bash access on his workstation, but not on the ssh bastion. He needs to ssh through the bastion to get to his workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the sss_override tool that was added in upstream 1.13 version and will be added to RHEL-7.2.

At the moment, the shell overrides are global.