# How to set different user options in SSSD by AD group

Tags: linux, active-directory, centos7, sssd

We've started a new project which (in part) involves integrating Linux systems with our existing AD infrastructure.  I've mostly gotten the hang of configuring SSSD and have it doing most of what we want, but one part escapes me, and I'm hoping some folks here can help.

I'm trying to assign user home directories (and maybe a couple of other settings) according to the AD user group.  Specifically, I want most users to have a normal home directory (/home/username); however, one particular group needs to have a common (shared) home dir that will kick off an application when they login (via their profile) instead of dropping them to a shell.

The commands for setting the home dir are not a problem for me; but how do I get SSSD to use a subset of settings for one particular AD group?

Ok, now I see this post ( [Setting shell for SSH directory users on a per-group basis in SSSD](https://serverfault.com/questions/728442/setting-shell-for-ssh-directory-users-on-a-per-group-basis-in-sssd) ) from 2015 that suggests using the sss_override tool, which shouldn't be a problem, but is there now a way to do this in the sssd.conf file, rather than with a separate tool?

Thank you,
Jason

Edit:  I looked over the other post, and went through the sss_override man page.  It won't do what I want to do.  You can override home directories at the individual level, but not group level.  Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 1):

There is no group-based override setting for sssd, sorry. Feel free to file an RFE..